# Creating metadata dynamically from a flat .csv file in CC

Tags: gooddata

I am having some difficulties on how to dynamically create a metadata, which need to be extracted from the header line of a flat .csv file in CC.

Usually, I manually define the metadata by select New Metadata --> Extract from flat file in CC. However the metadata of the file may changes with additional columns. Thus, I do not know the metadata of the file and I can not define it in this static approach.

It would be helpful if you could suggest a solution to create metadata dynamically and using this newly created metadata for connecting to other components. Perhaps an example graph file for demonstration would be great.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered this kind of [solution](https://developer.gooddata.com/downloads/cloud-connect/examples/dynamicMetadata.zip).

You just have to fill in flat .csv filename into csv readers and writers.

1. **MetaDataMaster.grf** - runs the graphs below.
2. **MetaDataCreator.grf** - creates metadata according to csv header and
   write it into meta_example.fmt file
3. **MetaDataUser.grf** - Reads csv according to created meta_example.fmt file - you can add there a reformat and use just some predefined fields.

You can run the 2nd and 3rd graph separately to test it.